# Why does remove directory give an error in this case?

Tags: javascript

So, I have been studying the filesystem module and also I am quite new to async and await
I don't understand why am I getting error here?

```
const fs = require("fs");
async function removeDir() {
    await fs.readdir("./trash", (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        for(filename of files){
            fs.unlinkSync(`./trash/${filename}`);
        }
        
        console.log("Cleared all files within directory");
    });

    await fs.rmdir("./trash", err => {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log("Removed Dir");
    });
}
removeDir();
```

Why is `fs.rmdir` getting executed before removing the files in the directory and I am getting an error that the directory isn't empty. Why isn't await working as I am expecting it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) in the main `fs` module doesn't return a promise, so using `await` on it has (almost) no effect, and certainly doesn't make the code wait until it's done its job. (That's why it has a callback, because that's how you know it's done.) Same for `rmdir`.

You can use the versions from the newer [fs/promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) instead.

---

Side note: Your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you never declare `filename`. Always be sure to declare your variables. (In this case, just put `const` in front of `filename`: `for (const filename of files) {`.) I also recommend using strict mode so that trying to assign to an undeclared identifier is the error it always should have been. These days, the best way to do that is to use JavaScript modules, which are always in strict mode. But you can use `"use strict";` at the top of a script or old-style Node.js module instead.

Comment: `These days, the best way to do that is to use JavaScript modules, which are always in strict mode. But you can use "use strict"; at the top of a script or old-style Node.js module instead.` I didn't get this part, can you please elaborate, I am a complete noob.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee - As we all were once. :-) Node.js has been around for a longish time, since before JavaScript had modules (added in ES2015). So Node.js has its own [CommonJS-like module mechanism](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html). But now JavaScript has [standard modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) often called ECMAScript Modules or ESM for short, which Node.js [now supports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) in addition to its own older module system. Native JS modules are always in strict mode, so you don't need `"use strict";` on them.